# Migrating to Spring 4, CommonsLogFactoryBean not found

Tags: logging, migration, spring-4

I´m migrating a project from spring 3.0.6 to 4.2.4 and in spring context configuration there is a reference to CommonsLogFactoryBean:

```
    <bean id="logger" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CommonsLogFactoryBean">
        <property name="logName" value="log"/>
    </bean>
```

CommonsLogFactoryBean has been deprecated in earlier version of Spring, and I can't find it in 4.2.4. How should be replaced??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your sample code for the following:

```
<bean id="logger"
      class="org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger">
    <constructor-arg value="log" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Worked for me.. Thanks !  (old and new listed here)  <bean id="thebeanOld" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CommonsLogFactoryBean">
  <property name="logName" value="mylogger"/>
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="thebean"
      class="org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger">
    <constructor-arg value="log" />
</bean>